# Adding product thumbnails to magento invoice PDF

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

How can I add the product thumbs to the PDFs

Comment: please check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8521290/cant-add-an-image-to-a-pdf-using-pdfbox

Comment: depends on which PDF package you are using for creating PDF. I have used DOM-PDF. 
http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-pdf-invoice-with-product-images-extension/

you can also [download](http://inchoo.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/PDF_Product_Images.zip) the source code from that page

Answer (score 0):

You may add product thumbnail image very easily by using Easy PDF Invoice extension
http://www.easypdfinvoice.com/blog/add-thumbnail-image-to-pdf/